# How to create a folder inside a tarball?

Tags: linux, tar

I created a tarball with multiple files. The rpm generator requires those files to be inside a folder. I don't want to move the files before generating the tar. Is there a way to create this folder while generating the tar or after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` option to `%setup` will allow you to create a directory and extract the files from the various sources within it.

Comment: For me that's not an option right now. But thank you anyway. I'll have to solve the problem in the tar, I can't change the rpm params.

Comment: Your other alternative is to write a custom tool, since even GNU tar doesn't support this.